# Can't open Label file darknet Yolo

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

[image]

I am following this tutorial :https://medium.com/techfeeds/yolo-single-image-train-single-object-training-9ba830076776   to train on single class using darknet19_448.conv.23 weights files
My images are of sizes ~300*200.

This is my .cfg file:

## Testing

batch=64

subdivisions=8

height=200

width=200

channels=3

classes=1

coords=4

num=5

softmax=1

jitter=.3

rescore=1

object_scale=5

noobject_scale=1

class_scale=1

coord_scale=1

absolute=1

thresh = .6

random=1

But, after copying data and cfg files along with train and test files, "Cant open label file" error shows up

Python : 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a really late response, but for anyone who has this issue it might be due to incorrect file path specifications for the .data file